# Prove using intermediate/mean value theorm

Tags: calculus, analysis, numerical-methods

Prove using intermediate/mean value theorem:

If $f \in C^3[a,b]$ then $$ f(b) = f(a) + (b-a)f^{'}(a) + \frac{f^{"}(a)}{2!} (b-a)^2 + \frac{f^{'''}(c)}{3!}(b-a)^3$$ where $c\in [a,b]$.

When I did working backwards i found out that $$ \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = f^{'}(a) + \frac{f^{"}(a)}{2!} (b-a) + \frac{f^{'''}(c)}{3!}(b-a)^2$$

and I know that by the mean value theorem I have $$f^{'}(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$ I'm getting these hints but I don't how to start proving to arrive at the said conclusion. Also, I'm quite confused of the last term $\frac{f^{'''}(c)}{3!}(b-a)^2$ why it uses $c$ and not $a$ or maybe it's supposed to be $a$? Please guide me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*
To prove it, a (simple) preliminary result may be needed:
Let $n \geq 1$; let $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$; let $B^{\xi} \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open ball around $\xi$; let $f: B^{\xi} \to \mathbb{R}$; let $f \in C^{n+1}$; then for all $x \in B^{\xi}$ we have
$$
E_{n}(x) := f(x) - \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{D^{k}f(\xi)}{k!}(x-\xi)^{k} = \frac{1}{n!}\int_{t=\xi}^{x}(x-t)^{n}D^{n+1}f(t).
$$ 
Note that $t \mapsto (x-t)^{n}$ is monotonic on $[\xi, x]$ for all $x \in B^{\xi}$ and that $D^{n+1}f$ is continuous on $[\xi,x]$ for all $x \in B^{\xi}$; by the mean-value theorem for integrals, for every $x \in B^{\xi}$ there is some $c \in [\xi,x]$ such that
$$
\int_{t=\xi}^{x}(x-t)^{n}D^{n+1}f(t) = D^{n+1}f(c)\int_{t=\xi}^{x}(x-t)^{n} = D^{n+1}f(c)\frac{(x-\xi)^{n+1}}{n+1},
$$
so 
$$
E_{n}(x) = \frac{D^{n+1}f(c)}{(n+1)!}(x - \xi)^{n+1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply Rolle's theorem on

$$h(x)=f(x)-p(x)+\frac{p(b)-f(b)}{(b-a)^{3}}(x-1)^{3}$$

where $$p(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2.$$